# Does macbook pro with ubuntu on it supports ethernet or not?

Tags: ubuntu, macbook, ethernet, macbook-pro

I saw [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro11-1/Saucy) an it was not clear:

> Ethernet: It works with a USB ethernet adapter. A
>   thunderbolt-to-ethernet adapter works only if it is plugged in before
>   boot. But it stops working after suspend. It also does not work if it
>   is plugged in after boot. The adapter is a PCIe card to the system and
>   the current Linux kernel does not support plug-and-play for this
>   adapter (or at least no support through the thunderbolt interface).

so i don't get it, is ethernet working (standard ethernet port) or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That text doesn't mention the onboard ethernet port (is there actually one on a MacBookPro ?)

What it explains in a not so clear way is for external ethernet adapters:

- USB ethernet adapters work fine
- Thunderbolt connected ethernet adapters are internally treated as PCIe devices and current Linux (may change in future) doesn't support hot-plug for PCIe devices.
  As result of that Thunderbolt connected ethernet adapters only work when they are plugged in before booting. They will stop working when you unplug/re-insert them while Linux is running and they will also stop working after a suspend/hibernate of the laptop.